# create touch test apps on swift 4 or above

Tags: swift, touch, detect

good day, i want to make an app to detect touch in the screen of ios device (iphone). but i am new in swift

i expect, when open the app, the interface of app like the image i attached,and if i touch the small square one, it will be dissappear from interface, and if i have touced all small square, they will dissappear one by one. if all small square is dissapear, the apps will show UIAlert success and exit. please help me and i need your guide. thank you
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoqOK.png)
the image on the link i attached

Comment: the squares can be UIViews, UIViews can contains UIButtons, UIButtons can do all the rest.

Comment: i have make the squares with many buttons like the image i have attached, but i dont know how if i swipe some buttons, the buttons which i swipe is going to dissapear [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/omsukCp.png)

Comment: you should implement the event [`touchDragInside`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event/1618240-touchdraginside), make the button dissappear when it calls the event

Comment: can you guide me about the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`collectionview`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) for creating the layout. Use some color for default collectionview cell color. And when a collection view cell is selected you change change the color to clear color. When all cells are selected present the alert.

```
class ViewControllerNew: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let collectionView = CollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    var arr = [Int]()
    var deletedArr = [Int]()
    var rowCount = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.register(Cell1.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell1")
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            let itemSpacing: CGFloat = 5
            let itemsInOneRow: CGFloat = 5
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: itemSpacing, left: itemSpacing, bottom: itemSpacing, right: itemSpacing)
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = itemSpacing
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = itemSpacing
            let cellWidth = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - (itemSpacing * 2) - ((itemsInOneRow - 1) * itemSpacing)) / itemsInOneRow
            let rowCount = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / cellWidth
            let newRowCount = Int((UIScreen.main.bounds.height - (itemSpacing * 2) - ((rowCount - 1) * itemSpacing)) / cellWidth)
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
            self.arr = Array(0..<newRowCount*Int(itemsInOneRow))
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return cell
    }
    func updateCells(_ touches: Set<UITouch>) {
        guard let location = touches.first?.location(in: collectionView),
                let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location),
                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else {
                    return
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        if !deletedArr.contains(indexPath.item) {
            deletedArr.append(indexPath.item)
        }
        if deletedArr.count == arr.count {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Game Finished", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { action in
                self.deletedArr.removeAll()
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
            alert.addAction(okBtn)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        updateCells(touches)
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        updateCells(touches)
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        updateCells(touches)
    }
}
class Cell1: UICollectionViewCell {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
class CollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, i have test it, but the square will disappear if touch the squares one by one, i expect i can touch dragging in the squares by finger. so how to make it? please help me

Comment: @macantiger I've created this programmatically without storyboard. Just copy all code from my answer and paste in a new swift file. Then update the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in your `AppDelegate` as `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = ViewControllerNew()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}`

Comment: thanks it ran, but how can i make it in storyboard? because i have another view controller in storyboard, then we can continue to this touch test

Comment: You can connect the collectionview from storyboard and change collectionview subclass